# C++ Function Returning 0 instead of 0.35

Tags: c++, function

I am trying to call the decimal function from the main function. This function returns what is to the right of the decimal point of any given number. When I print out the value of rightSide that the decimal function is returning, the value is correct (0.35). However after I call the decimal function from the main function and try to save the returned value, the returned value (variable a in main) is 0. Basically, the two values I am printing out should be the same but they aren't.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip> 
using namespace std;

int integer(double number) {
    int leftSide;
    leftSide = number;
    return leftSide;
}

int decimal (double number) {
    int leftSide;
    double rightSide;
    leftSide = integer(number);
    rightSide = number - leftSide;
    cout << "rightSide: " << rightSide
    return rightSide;
}

int main() {
    double x;
    x = decimal(3.25);
    cout << "x: " << x << endl;
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Because you've declared the return type as an int?

Comment: Alternatively, you could use [`modf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/modf)

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, integers dont't do decimal places, by the annoying fact they are integers, and not decimal numbers. Perhaps consider a type that can handle the decimal point?

```
double decimal (double number) {
    int leftSide;
    double rightSide;
    leftSide = integer(number);
    rightSide = number - leftSide;
    return rightSide;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be an academic assignment. If you are required to return "what is right to the decimal point" as an integer (no decimals) number part of the exercise might be to actually multiply by 10 enough times so that the result can be returned as an integer.

Answer (score 1):

`int decimal (double number)` should be `double decimal(double number)` also you can't return a fraction as you command return code.

Comment: Yes, the double decimal fixed it. Thanks!